# C++ Box2D, Simulating Dynamic Body behavior with Kinematic Body

Tags: c++, box2d

Ive got a problem with Box2D.

I´ve coded a game like this Warcraft 3 map.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PKa1CNw6Q5A

Where you control a character and can throw fireballs which can collide with objects.

For the collision between Fireballs and Pillars for example I used kinematic bodies for both (Normally they dont collide, but with a hack i got it working) which works just fine because I just need to track the collision and I cant use dynamic bodies because I dont want them to be pressed apart if they collide (OnTouch behavior is implemented in spell script).

But now I need collision between Pillars and Characters, so basically I want them to behave like rubber balls, when the Character is thrown with velocity x against the pillar it should bounce off. But for this I would need the behavior of a dynamic body, so is there an easy way to simulate the behavior of a dynamic body with kinematic bodies? (maybe overwriting something?)

Ive no clue how Box2D works intern and would be glad if anyone understands my question and can help me.

Comment: You can call contact->SetEnabled(false) in the BeginContact callback if you don't want the contact to do any collision response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need to use dynamic bodies for everything, but have more explicit control over how they respond after a collision.

For example, all the "projectile" like things should be sensors or use the group ID or mask bits to make it so they don't physically collide with other objects.  Even though there is not a collision response, there is a callback you can create to detect the collision and decide what to do based on it.

**Hacking the physics seems like you could destabilize something that works reliably...having done this myself, I appreciate the inclination.**

Look at [this tutorial](https://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/collision-filtering) and the one immediately after it.  They really have great information (and no, they are not mine...dang it).

For some more info on contact filtering, take a look at this [other article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20440183/how-to-make-two-way-platform-box2d-body/20441140#20441140).

Comment: that somehow helped me, I got now 99% of the behavior I wanted, the only thing I didnt get was that when 1 character moves into another, the other one is pushed away but ill fix that somehow, thanks

Comment: I think you probably need to add contact filtering of some kind.  I added a second reference in the post.  If you don't want the bodies to collie, you can make them part of different groups (friends bump, enemies damage each other and bump, etc.).  One of the key things to figure out is **what** you want the response to be based on different groups.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to take a look at [Chipmunk](http://chipmunk-physics.net/) library!

It's a physic engine (2D), written in C. I've used it in my projects, works very well!